# Incomplete Monitors

Tags: obd

I changed my Hyundai 2000 Accent battery and My CAT and EVAP monitors will not complete.  I have tried a generic drive cycle and monitors will not complete.  Any suggestions.

Comment: How full is the gas tank? 50% full should be best. What is the ambient temperature of where you are? If it's too cold (below freezing) the monitors may not run.